# How do I pass args to a python program using Cloud Run deploy with CloudBuild and Uvicorn?

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, uvicorn

I have a cloud run service which I deploy using Cloudbuild and uvicorn:

```
CMD exec uvicorn src.api:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT
```

I deploy with `gcloud run deploy ...`
This works fine. Now I want to pass in a variable value that is set at deployment and can be used by the container's python code. I try adding:

```
--args='_arg1=$${_Value}'
```

but when I try to deploy it fails to start with:

```
cannot resolve init executable: error finding executable "_arg1=${_Value}" in PATH...
```

I assume this is the container is thinking that parameter is a py program to run.

What should I be doing instead?